# How do I tokenize this input sentences by the following stopwords ("!", "?", ".", “,”)?

Tags: python, tokenize

I imported sent_tokenize from nltk.tokenize and thus use the method called sent_tokenize(input). Below are the the solutions and function I've used to solve this but I keep on getting failed. I tried looking on the net and tried to understand every method used out there but still it's not working.
I have no idea what I did wrong ? Please help.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
def tokenise(input, expected_output):
  input = "Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?"
  expected_output = ['Excuse me', 'where can I find a chicken rice shop']
  result = sent_tokenize(input)
print('Pass' if result == expected_output else 'Failed!')

# Please make sure all test cases return 'Pass'
tokenise(tcase1, tans1)
tokenise(tcase2, tans2)
tokenise(tcase3, tans3)
print('Pass' if result == expected_output else 'Failed!')



Test case 1:
Input: Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop? Expected output: ["Excuse me", "where can I find a chicken rice shop"]

Test case 2:
Input: OMG!!! It is Friday....where should we go for dinner? Expected output: ["OMG", "It is Friday", "where should we go for dinner"]

Test case 3:
Input: He’s nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready. Expected output: [“He’s nervous”, “but on the surface he looks calm and ready”]
```

Comment: In your `tokenise` function, why are you overwriting `input` and `expected_output` when those are being passed into the function? Also, you should rename your variable `input` to something else. `input` is a built-in function in Python (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: @GarrettHyde I've tried to rename it but it still fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the overwriting of your function arguments inside the function and the variable naming issue, your code is working exactly as it should.

`sent_tokenize()` splits full sentences. Ellipsis and commas are not punctuation that end sentences and so there will be no `split` for those characters.

Your code, but working:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

def tokenise(inp, expected_output):  
  res = sent_tokenize(inp)  
  print(res, 'Pass' if res == expected_output else 'Failed!')

# Please make sure all test cases return 'Pass'
#Test case 1:
tokenise("Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?", ["Excuse me", "where can I find a chicken rice shop"])

#Test case 2:
tokenise("OMG!!! It is Friday....where should we go for dinner?",  ["OMG", "It is Friday", "where should we go for dinner"])

#Test case 3:
tokenise("He’s nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready",  ["He’s nervous", "but on the surface he looks calm and ready"])
```

Each of these return `Failed!!` as I would expect they should.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the question above by using only split method ?

Comment: `re.split()` may be a better avenue. I believe `split()` can only work on one delimiter at a time so it will get either nested and ugly or hack-ish. The hack-ish approach would be to replace every punctuation with the same character `output = input.replace('.','|').replace(',','|').replace('!','|').replace('?','|').split('|')` or similar. Probably more cleanup will be needed for repeated delimiters, but at least you aren't in a nested hell scape.